# Clicks on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have buttons,many of them i want to click on them and between each click there should be 0.1 sec delay how i can do it?
buttons(multiple of them):

```
<div class="egg" id="egg1" onclick="egg.play(1);"></div>
<div class="egg" id="egg2" onclick="egg.play(2);"></div>
```

and so on until 27 buttons so how i can click on those 27 buttons?

here is what i use it works fine for 1 button any way how to make it for 27 button and delay of 0.1 sec between each click?also i want it in function, because i want to call the function...

```
function clickegg(){
    $("#egg1").click();


    setTimeout(clickegg, 1000);
}
```

no problem if it's jquery or javascript.thanks

Comment: @TheFool no its not attempt from my side to solve it. im a begginer

Comment: @TheFool sorry if i bothered you but as you can see in my code i tried but that's the best i could do...i've just finished jquery course...i was going to make 27 functions... but i knew there is easier way to do it so that's why i came here.i think i should learn more about loops/conditionals.

Comment: Ok no worries we all start out somewhere, I gave you the keyword to solve this, and all answers here are using it in some way, well the recursive one is a bit different but still the same idea. Please check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration e.g.g. afterwards you should be able to think of a solution on your own. Maybe also drop jQuery, it's a bit outdated and you learn more with vanilla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template string + recursion with terminating condition:

```
function clickegg(which=1){
    $(`#egg${which}`).click();

    if(which < 27) {
      setTimeout(() => clickegg(which+1), 100);
    }
}
```

clicks #egg1, then #egg2 after 0.1s, then #egg3, and so on until hitting the final number.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to have a variable outside the function that you can increment (add one to) every time the function is called. If you want it to loop infinitely, then you can use the modulo operator (`%`) to do this, otherwise you can have it just stop after clicking button 27.

```
var clickegg = (function () {
  var buttonNum = 1;
  function clickegg(){
    $("#egg" + buttonNum).click();

    // to repeat forever, uncomment out the following line:
    //buttonNum = (buttonNum + 1) % 27 + 1;
    // to stop after #27, leave the following line in:
    if (buttonNum++ > 27) return;
    setTimeout(clickegg, 100);
  }
  return clickegg;
})();

// invoke it the first time
clickegg();
```